# How to build a real SAPUI5 library

Tags: gruntjs, gulp, sapui5

I've noticed that [grunt-openui5](https://github.com/SAP/grunt-openui5) provides a task to generate a library-preload.json file. But I can't find any information on how to build a fully functional SAPUI5 library?

I'm thinking of a gulp/grunt build generating all necessary library metafiles, less compilation and combining of multiple .less files into one library.css

Comment: It also provides the functionality about theming: https://github.com/SAP/grunt-openui5#openui5_theme

Comment: Please check if this info helps : https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/docs/developing.md

Comment: Not directly. But this actually helps a lot: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/docs/controllibraries.md Thx!